# Get GraphQL Count Function to populate React Plotly Graph - Map function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, strapi

I need your help to populate a graph with data.

What i want to do is this:

```
const chartData = [{
    values: [25,54, 20],
    labels: ['mitre', 'some', 'ok'],
    type: 'pie'
  }]
```

[pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SVQG.png)

Currently my code is like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

const testare = gql`
query GetIntell {
  webs(
    sort: "dateAdded:desc"
    pagination: { start: 0, limit: 90 },
    filters: {dateAdded: {eq: "2022-03-15"}, site   :{eq: "val"}}
  ) {
    data {
      id
      attributes {
 ...
      }
    }
  }
}
`

export default function Test() {

  const { loading, error, data }= useQuery(testare)
  if (loading) return <p>Loading data...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>`Error! ${error}`</p>;

 const chartData = [{
    values: [data.webs.data
      .map((threat) => {
        return {
          data: [threat.count]
        }
        
      })],
    labels: ['mitre'],
    type: 'pie'
  }]

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Plot
        data= {chartData}
        layout={ {width: 1000, height: 540, title: "Plot"} }
        //layout={ layout}
        config={{responsive: true}}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Instead of actual values, I am getting an array of objects.

I need to return the length of the array i.e 36 and not all 36  objects  ==> see here [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qnCk.png) Please help. I don't know hoe to do a map inside a map.

If you could help, I would owe you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This was my answer:

```
 const chartData = [{
    values: [data.webs.data.length],
    labels: ['mitre'],
    type: 'pie'
  }]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).